# Can socket() fail with EINPROGRESS

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is it possible for the `socket()` function to fail with `EINPROGRESS` in Linux? Note that I am specifically asking about `socket()`, not `connect()` or others.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/socket.html) does not list `EINPROGRESS` as a possible error code. However the manpage for `socket()` in Linux says:

> Other errors may be generated by the underlying protocol modules.

Is there any circumstances in which this call can actually fail with `EINPROGRESS`?

Comment: I don't see how. There's nothing for it to be in progress about. There is no I/O involved: just creation of a socket FD. Why do you ask?

Comment: I think the manpage is unambiguous here: There may be protocols, which in fact _do_ return `EINPROGRESS` on a call to `socket()`. But none of the commonly used protocols do so. It is impossible to return the refering filedescriptor then, so it had to be a hard error, which somewhat conflicts with the meaning of `EINPROGRESS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EINPROGRESS means the operation is now in progress. It would block because of an external reason : wait for a remote action or a local device.

socket() is only creating an entry in the memory of the system : there is no reason to wait for any remote action or any device.

But if it were able to return EINPROGRESS, you would have nothing to wait for.

With file handles and socket handles, you can use select() in order to wait for the system to be ready. But if the socket() itself does not return anything, you have nothing to wait on.

I see no reason for socket() to return EIPROGRESS but it would be a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you were looking for:

You'll have to check the corresponding [Linux kernel source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/security/security.c) (`kernel/net/socket.c`) throughly to be 100% sure. Glancing through the code, it doesn't look like `EINPROGRESS` is returned anywhere. However, there are runtime dependent calls in there, so its difficult to say just from static code analysis.